# Pipedrive delete a deal with API

Tags: php, pipedrive-api

I am trying to delete a deal using through the API. The code I have written is below , but its not working. I am not able to figure out where to add the Method "DELETE" while making the call.I am not getting any error message in output. Please suggest.

```
<?php
$api_token = "myapitoken";

 $url = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deal?api_token=" . $api_token;

 $deal = array(
  'id' => 375,
  'method' => 'DELETE'
  );

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $deal);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 $result = json_decode($output);


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting deal on pivedrive can be done using following code

```
$id= "deal_id";
$url = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals/". $id ."?api_token=" . $api_token;

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your api token is a postfield too.

Maybe this way:

```
$url = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deal";

$deal = array(
'api_token'=> $api_token,
'id' => 375,
'method' => 'DELETE'

);
```

Comment: I changed this to the below code and now it says "Please provide atleast one item to delete"

Comment: $deal = array(
'id' => 375

);
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $deal);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 curl_close($ch);
echo $result